# materialize css: Always show side-nav even on mobile?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am using materialize css. I'm using side nav and want to set visible even on mobile. I'm using following code for this but its not working.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .side-nav{
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 100;
    }
}
```

Its keep on hiding on small screen.

Comment: Have you removed `hide-on-med-and-down` from the side-nav default code?

Comment: it was requirment to use material design

Comment: hide-on-med-and-down is not applied

Comment: @user3576148 materialize is a frontend toolkit similar to bootstrap and has its own grid system. I actually prefer the semantics of materialize's grid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Materialize uses CSS transformations to show/hide the side nav, so altering the visibility or opacity will not help you here. A very quick solution is just to fix the translateX transformation at 0. This should make your nav visible at all times.

```
.side-nav {
    transform: translateX(0%) !important;
}
```

Comment: In v1.0.0 it's `sidenav` rather than `side-nav`.